# How do I fix this section of code to allow the user to get their favorites from Firebase Realtime db? even with uid working, user can't view favorites

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Here is the error message being returned:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

Here is the section of code from the FavoritesContext.jsx component that I need help on:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        if (!uid) {
            return;
         } else
     db.ref(`users/${uid}/favorites`).on("value", (snapshot) => {
         console.log("favorites: ", snapshot.toJSON());

         const results = Object.entries(snapshot.toJSON() || {}).map(
           ([id, props]) => ({
              id,
              ...props,
              })
            );
          setFavorites(results);
            });
            }, []);
```

Here is the where the db comes from in my Base.js component:

```
export const db = firebase.database(uiConfig);
```

Here is the pertinent code from my AuthContext.js component:

```
    export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
     const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
     const [pending, setPending] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setPending(false);
     });
     }, []);
```

Comment: "Cannot read property uid of null" implies that `firebase.auth().currentUser` is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from firebase official documentation

> You can also get the currently signed-in user by using the currentUser property. If a user isn't signed in, currentUser is null:

you are getting uid null because your user is not yet signed in.

you can read more here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: using your suggestion, I updated the code to this:

 useEffect(() => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid;
    if (user != null) {
        uid = user.uid;
      db.ref(`users/${uid}/favorites`).on("value", (snapshot) => {
        console.log("favorites: ", snapshot.toJSON());

        const results = Object.entries(snapshot.toJSON() || {}).map(
          ([id, props]) => ({
            id,
            ...props,
      })
        );
        setFavorites(results);
    })};
  }, []);
  
however, it's still not working

Comment: did you signed in with the user ?

Comment: yes.  i was able to get the user signed in.  however, it would not render the user's favorites, nor allow any recipes to be favorited by the user

Comment: should I present this other issue as another question?